# Create gradient on UIImage for text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I am trying to replicate the gradient found on the bottom of these album artwork image views. It makes it very easy to read the text no matter what the background is.

How would I recreate this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gradient effect is known as a floor fade.

The gradient starts with 0.0 alpha black at the middle of the image, to about 0.2 alpha black at the bottom of the image.

You could add a CAGradientLayer to your image, along the lines of:

```
CAGradientLayer *bottomFade = [CAGradientLayer layer];
bottomFade.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, CGRectGetHeight(self.imageView.bounds), CGRectGetWidth(self.imageView.bounds), -(CGRectGetHeight(self.imageView.bounds) / 2.0));
bottomFade.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0);
bottomFade.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.0);
bottomFade.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.0f] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.2f] CGColor], nil];
[image.layer addSublayer:bottomFade];
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, for some weird reason the fade only took up half the width and height. I just took the bounds and multiplied the height & width by 2.

Comment: I botched the coordinates.  Fixed!